# mongoid pluck - not returning correct values with default values in model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I have a User model where there is a department field which has a default value of "Engineering".

This field was introduced 2 months after our website went live,and since its mongo, there was no migration.

When I try to get the object using where, correct value is returned

```
 User.find_by(:name => "John).department
```

However, if I try to pluck values, it returns nil and not the default value.

```
 User.limit(2).pluck(:department)
```

returns

```
[nil,"Finance"]
```

I researched a bit and came across this blog post http://ahmadsherif.com/blog/2013/01/29/mongoid-default-fields-can-give-you-hard-time/

I think I am facing the same issue. Is there any work around for this? I chose to go with pluck because it's not memory intensive and saves time.

Comment: How are you setting the default value? Is it actually being saved in the DB? Because MongoDB does not have "real" database level defaults like a traditional SQL db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically the behaviour here can be explained by the difference in how MongoDB deals with default values vs a traditional relational database like Postgres.

In the SQL world you set defaults via the database schema and the DB will fill a NULL field everytime you insert a row.

Since MongoDB is schemaless document fields have a default value of nil, which cannot be changed* since there is no schema where we could define defaults on the database level. Instead defaults are implemented on the application level. For Mongoid this means when you initialize a new model instance it will fill in default values if they are nil.

In ActiveRecord terms it would look like this:

```
class Thing < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_initialize :set_default_foo, if: -> { self.foo.nil? }

  private 
    def set_default_foo
      self.foo = "bar"
    end
end
```

However if you have existing documents and add a new field or defaults to an existing field Mongoid does not update the existing documents for you!

So how does this explain these two cases?

```
User.find_by(:name => "John").department
User.limit(2).pluck(:department)
```

In the first case you a pulling a document out of storage and using it to inialize a model instance. When the model instance is initialized a callback is run which sets the default values.

When `.pluck` is called on the hand Mongoid pulls the values directly from the store without initializing any model instances. Thus for any "legacy" documents it will return a nil value.

To remedy this you you need to set the default value for any document with a nil.

```
User.where(department: nil).update_all(department: 'engineering')
```